# Writing a property to set color value in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, properties, colors, typeconverter

```
public string LabelColor
    {
        get { return Convert.ToString(this.label1.ForeColor); }
        set { this.label1.ForeColor =Color(value); }
    }
```

I am trying set "value" as forecolor to the label forecolor property, but here "value" is 
string and i need to convert it into type color. how can i do that.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code - based on `Color.FromName` Method

```
set { this.label1.ForeColor = Color.FromName(value); }
```